# How can we handle Digital Signature in Selenium with Appium

Tags: ionic-framework, uwp, appium, digital-signature, ui-automation

I have a application for testing but in application has Signature Surface also ,how can i automate this application with selenium. application in ionic cordova WebApp platform. Please suggest me that how can i automate this Signature.i also used Visual Studio for that.

Can any one suggest me that how can i automate my UWP Desktop App.

Comment: how do you implement the signature surface? is it an `InkCanvas` control?

Comment: Yes its a InkCanvas and platform is UWP